# How update Unity (14.04LTS) at the same version that 15.10?

Tags: unity

First sorry for my grammar.

I wanna update Unity version from my Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS to the same version that appears on Ubuntu 15.10 or 15.04.

I searched on Google but I don't find anything.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: OK, solved. I understand that If I want new Unity version I must update OS enterely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unity Desktop Environment version is specific of each version of Ubuntu:

- Unity 7.2.5 for Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
- Unity 7.3.3 for Ubuntu 15.10

To upgrade the final release of Ubuntu 15.10 released in 22/10/2015 follow the steps below:

Type Alt+F2 to open the dash command or Ctrl+Alt+T to open the terminal.

Use anyone of commands below, whatever:

```
sudo update-manager -c

sudo do-release-upgrade -p -m desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose what you prefer: polished stable soft or new versions with bugs. If you want to use new unity you have to upgrade to 15.04, and then to 15.10.

Comment: Then can't I update unity dash only? I wanna update the interfaz, but no the OS enterely.